# Excel powery query: Saving over data and updating tables

Tags: excel, powerquery

Good day all,

I currently am sitting with a bit of a challenge which i wonder you could assist.

Every day i recieve data from our investment `prodivodrs`

```
A        b        C           D 

date    price    units      amount 
today    1         1          1
yesterday 1        1           1
etc
```

I have to reference and check yesterdays units and todays units are the same and flag any changes to the investment `prodivdor`, obviuosuly the new units for today cannot be referenced because they are new.

I need to ascertain on todays sheet and yesterdays sheet that for example the data 4 weeks ago monday are all the same.

I have already built the architecutre of the sheet where what table goes where plus the lookups.

the challenge i am having is every day I save over the folder
T+0 (is todays files that are generated)

and the folder T-1 (the files that were generated yesterday)

```
T+0 = todays data
T-1 = yesterdays data
```

There are approximately 15 sheets with about 3-20 sheets that i have to compare.

When ever i save over the sheets it then corrupts the power query that I have built saying i cannot refernce it.

Any way that I can save over the data without creating errors so that the rest of the spreddy can work?

Thanks

I have played around with what I know but nothing has worked.

Have tried changing file names, index matching look ups, used VBA, and have recently started working in power query which i believe to be the answer but i seem to not be able to save over the excel files and then re update the data in order to reference  etc

Comment: Can you just save the old data files in a directory and read all of them in each day ?

Comment: You're not providing a whole lot of detail. Are you saying that every time you receive new files they are called the same and have the same structure? Or not? Because if you overwrite your source files with something that has the same name and structure, nothing should break. Some minimal reproducible data would help, because what you have provided doesn't really do much.

Answer (score 0):

Make a table of historical data.

To do this, make a query that reads the data you'll be needing tomorrow. Call that "Historical"

Then duplicate this query and call it "Hospital - Incoming".

Then edit the power query editor, load the Historical query to a new worksheet. Then click on it and load that table as a *new* query. Call it "Historical - Previous".

And now, change your Historical query to instead be

```cs
Table.Distinct(
  Table.Combine({
    #"Historical - Previous",
    #"Historical - Incoming"
  })
)
```

Now you have a table that keeps growing and appends new information as it gets it.

(Later you'll probably want to change Historical again to remove old data, but you can do that later.)

Another benefit; If you change your existing queries that provide this data to get this data from  "Historical" (or "Historical - Previous" if you want to force yourself to *know* you have cached the data before using it) then you've not only solved your problem, you will suddenly gain the ability to compare any two dates that you have history for!